# Menu option items suddenly unresponsive after working throughout development

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have an app which I am working on which is working completely fine at the moment but I've suddenly encountered a strange problem.

I have five options on my options menu which is either an action bar or can be summoned by the menu button (pre 3.0. Android devices).

HOWEVER, they have suddenly stopped working completely. I haven't changed the code at all, the menu items are the same as they have always been but when I tap them none of the activities load and LogCat doesn't produce anything related to the problem.

Anyone encountered this issue when using Eclipse? I have the same problem on my android tablet and android phone. I have cleaned the project, refreshed it and deleted the gen/ folder after researching similar problems.

Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: please show us the relevant code.

Comment: the thing is I have a lot of classes and XML files but they haven't been changed since yesterday and the app was working yesterday. Just wondering if this was a known issue/bug with Eclipse.

Comment: Delete your gen & bin folders in eclipse and then re-build. Some times re-starting eclipse works as well.

Comment: Still no success after deleting folders, re-building or re-starting :(